# Controlling Chrome coverage feature with chromedriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way currently to programmatically pull a coverage report from Chrome while Chrome is running under selenium or other automated control software?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [this article](https://www.gideonpyzer.com/blog/runtime-coverage-using-chrome-devtools/), there is a reference in the comments that there's no way to export this data right now but there is [a feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717195).

There's another article [here](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/03/29/how-does-chrome-code-coverage-work.html) that talks about how the feature works and in the comments someone asks this same question. The response was that there's an API [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Profiler/#method-startPreciseCoverage) that maybe you could take advantage of using a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Selenium only has access to the browser context via `execute_script` aimed to execute `window.__coverage__;` to collect the Front-end's coverage data. So, you need to instrument your source code using `nyc` and parse the returned value.